# pip install automl gets stuck

Tags: python, installation, pip, automl

I've tried to install automl (https://pypi.org/project/automl/) from PyCharm and conda but consistently get stuck at the end of the following text:

```
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess>=0.70.7 in c:\path1\path2\path3\test1\venv\lib\site-packages (from pathos<0.3.0,>=0.2.1->automl) (0.70.11.1)
Collecting multiprocess>=0.70.7
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.11-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.10.zip (2.4 MB)
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.9.tar.gz (1.6 MB)
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.8.tar.gz (1.6 MB)
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.7.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
```

I don't know why it keeps trying to access subsequently older versions of multiprocess and have no idea how to proceed from here.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I'm using auto_ml as opposed to automl.  It gets stuck on that same package multiprocess-0.70.7.tar.gz.  I'm using python 3.9.4.  I found this: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/167 which talks about the same issue for python 3.8

Comment: looks like it's for python 3.4-3.6 https://github.com/ClimbsRocks/auto_ml/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt on pycharm, do `start venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install automl --no-cache-dir`

Comment: Thanks. It still gets stuck. The only difference is that now instead of saying 'cached', it says 'downloading'

Comment: Can you try ```start venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install multiprocess==0.70.11.1 --no-cache-dir``` to make sure that the system has a working multiprocess or if it gives you an error why it can't download.

Comment: it says "Requirements already satisfied", so the problem is most likely what comes after multiprocess. The thing is, I can't see what comes after it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by lowering the Python version from 3.9 to 3.6.